# sort the list and rearrange in python3

Tags: python-3.x

list A of elements of length `N`, ranging from `1 to N`. All elements may not be present in the array. If the element is not present then there will be `-1` present in the array. Rearrange the array such that `A[i] = i` and if i is not present display `-1` at that place.

my code in python 3

```
l= list(map(int, input().split()))
p=sorted(l)
j=[z for z in range(p[0],p[-1]+1)]
for i in range(1,p[-1]):
  if i is not j:
    for d in range(p[-1]):
      j[d]=-1
print(' '.join(map(str,p)))
```

here is input & expected output:

```
input: 4 7 -1 9 -1 5 3 -1 -1 -1
expected output: -1 -1 -1 3 4 5 -1 7 -1 9
```

Output getting:

```
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 3 4 5 7 9
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There's a simpler method:

let

```
l = [int(i) for i in "4 7 -1 9 -1 5 3 -1 -1 -1".split()]
l  # input
Out:
[4, 7, -1, 9, -1, 5, 3, -1, -1, -1]
```

create a list with `-1`'s with length `len(l)`:

```
p = [-1] * len(l)
p
Out: 
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
```

Iterate through `l` and assign values to `p` if element in `l` is not `-1`:

```
for i in l:
    if i != -1:
        p[i] = i
p
Out:
[-1, -1, -1, 3, 4, 5, -1, 7, -1, 9]
```

It's faster solution, because there's no  searching of element `i` in list `j`, and it gives desired output.

**Edit**:
as a function:

```
l= list(map(int, input().split()))

def rearrange(l):
    p = [-1] * len(l)
    for i in l:
        if i != -1:
            p[i] = i
    return p
```

Comment: @BlueSheepToken As the task is "Rearrange the array such that A[i] = i and if i is not present display -1 at that place.", I've written a cycle which assigns only non-`-1`values from source list to positions equals it's values to get desired output